# ImageViewer in WPF

Tags: wpf, image-viewer

Hi everyone I would like to implement an ImageViewer (like the one in Facebook for example) in a WPF application

I already have a ListBox whith my pictures, it works well. But I would like to add pop "image full size" when the user double click on one of them. (something like in FB, with a fade out of the background etc).
Currently I'm thinking of to use a Window...Do you have a better idea of what I should use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a [Popup control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx).

It comes with some some built in (but very limited) animations, like `fade`, see [PopupAnimation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.popupanimation.aspx)

I'd try that and if it doesn't fit your needs, I second [bflosabre91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431524/user1431524) oppionion and would use a separate opacity animated window.

But bear in mind that with an additional window you could have negative side effects e.g always sync the window positions correctly, handle task switches (ie. correctly hide the window in the taskbar/tasklist)

Comment: I would not recommend popups for this, they are mainly meant for things that are displayed for a short time. They have the property of always being on top of windows, so if the popup is still open and the user switches to another application it will be on top of that.

Comment: I don't know how the image viewer in facebook looks like, I thought of a simple 'Click me' and 'show the image larger' control; then a popup is ideal as it is simple and lightweight. 
But you are right: In case you need navigation buttons and additional stuff then a separate control in a window definitely suits better.

Answer (score 1):

i would probably use a window for that as well. Then you can easily put an opacity animation when the window loads to give it the fade in and fade out effect